# React state not getting updated in Functional Component after fetching from axios and using react-router

Tags: axios, react-router, hook, react-functional-component, react-state

So I am trying to update state in the parent component from the child component (child component calls axios) and then I want to send this state from parent component to another child component via route but the state is not getting updated, maybe because I am sending state initailly in the route, can anyone tell me the correct way of sending the updated state in react-route?

Code Snippet:

```html
const ParentComponent = () =>{
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
...
...
...
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/child1Component"
          render={() => <Child1Component setData={setInfo} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/child2Component"
          render={() => (
            <Child2Component dataApp={info} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
}

const Child1Component = (props) =>{
axios
    .get("URL", {
     
    })
    .then((response) => {
      props.setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I want the updated state value to be passed as props in the Child2Component, for now it is not updating initial state.

Comment: Hi Amit! maybe create an intermediate function that will then call `setInfo` on your parent component, that way you can console log if that method is being called.

Comment: can you please explain more with an example? Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this example https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bartik-0xdu5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case, I have to pass updated state to the route as props, and it is taking the initial (not updated) value to the component, while you are displaying it, how can I make sure that the updated state (info) pass into the props?